# Is Per-User Retrieval supports open-source vectorstore chromadb?

Tags: llm, conversational-ai

From the `langchain` documentation - [Per-User Retrieval](https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/question_answering/per_user)

> When building a retrieval app, you often have to build it with multiple users in mind. This means that you may be storing data not just for one user, but for many different users, and they should not be able to see eachother’s data. This means that you need to be able to configure your retrieval chain to only retrieve certain information.

The documentation has an example implementation using `PineconeVectorStore`. Does chromadb support multiple users? If yes, can anyone help with an example on how the per-user retrieval can be implemented using the opensource `ChromaDB`?